# Proper style conventions for anonymous interface declarations?

Tags: java, swing, coding-style, anonymous-inner-class

I am using the `ActionListener` interface in order to add interactivity a `JButton` object. This is how Eclipse formats the code below for me with `Ctrl+Shift+F`, but what is the proper styling conventions for a situation like this when I want to create an anonymous interface?

```
updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    }
});
```

And this:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: You should place `{` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java 8, there are two alternatives:

1) Using a lambda:

```
final ActionListener actionListener = e -> {
    //do stuff
};
```

And

```
new JButton().addActionListener(e -> {
    //do stuff
});
```

2) Using a method reference:

```
public void toStuff(final ActionEvent e) {
    //do stuff        
}
```

And then:

```
final ActionListener actionListener = this::doStuff;
```

or

```
new JButton().addActionListener(this::doStuff);
```

More generally, the rest of formatting is opinion based. I, for example, prefer [Egyptian brackets](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/). But what is **not** opinion based is that you should use **consistent** formatting for all code - let your IDE do that for you.

Comment: Interesting, but could you elaborate on the `doStuff()` method? I'm assuming that I'm allowed to place it anywhere I want, as long as it's within the scope of the `JButton` object.

Comment: @JohnH I'm not going to regurgitate what the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) covers. But, in short, you can put it anywhere as long as you can _reference_ it. A `static` method in a utility `class`. A method on a `class` you have an instance of. _Anywhere_.